# What is the best way to install Jetty on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, java

Is there anyone here who downloaded and installed Jetty on ubuntu? Please help. How did you install it? I've been trying for two days and I cannot make it work. Finally I did a clean install of ubuntu but still I am unable to download and install jetty. I tried these tutorials, none worked for me:

- [Ubuntu 12.04 – Install Jetty 9](https://superuser.com/questions/691131/tar-cannot-open-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [How to Install Jetty Web Server in Ubuntu](https://degreesofzero.com/article/19)
- [Nginx Proxy to Jetty for Java
  Apps](http://sacharya.com/nginx-proxy-to-jetty-for-java-apps/)

I am running ubuntu 13.10.

---

**EDIT 4**

```
a@a:~$ sudo apt-get install jetty libjetty8-extra-java libjetty8-java libjetty-extra-java libjetty-extra libjetty-java-doc jetty8 libjetty8-java-doc libjetty-java jsvc default-jre-headless apache2-utils adduser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
adduser is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjetty8-extra-java : Depends: libtomcat7-java (>= 7.0.28) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

**EDIT3**

```
a@a:~$ sudo apt-get install jetty openjdk-7-jre-headless libjetty8-extra-java libjetty8-java libjetty-extra-java libjetty-extra libjetty-java-doc jetty8 libjetty8-java-doc libjetty-java jsvc java5-runtime-headless apache2-utils adduser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package java5-runtime-headless is a virtual package provided by:
  openjdk-6-jre-headless 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu2.1
  gcj-4.8-jre-headless 4.8.1-10ubuntu9
  gcj-4.6-jre-headless 4.6.4-1ubuntu1
  openjdk-7-jre-headless 7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3
  gcj-jre-headless 4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3
  default-jre-headless 1:1.7-48ubuntu2
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'java5-runtime-headless' has no installation candidate
a@a:~$
```

---

**EDIT 2**

```
a@a:~$ sudo apt-get install jetty libjetty8-extra-java libjetty8-java libjetty-extra-java libjetty-extra libjetty-java-doc jetty8 libjetty8-java-doc libjetty-java jsvc java5-runtime-headless apache2-utils adduser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package java5-runtime-headless is a virtual package provided by:
  openjdk-6-jre-headless 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu2.1
  gcj-4.8-jre-headless 4.8.1-10ubuntu9
  gcj-4.6-jre-headless 4.6.4-1ubuntu1
  openjdk-7-jre-headless 7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3
  gcj-jre-headless 4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3
  default-jre-headless 1:1.7-48ubuntu2
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'java5-runtime-headless' has no installation candidate
a@a:~$
```

---

**EDIT 1**

I tried [Dumindu Mahawela](https://askubuntu.com/users/224082/dumindu-mahawela)'s answer but this is what I get:

```
a@a:~$ sudo apt-get install jetty libjetty8-extra-java libjetty8-java libjetty-extra-java libjetty-extra libjetty-java-doc jetty8 libjetty8-java-doc libjetty-java jsvc default-jre-headless apache2-utils adduser
[sudo] password for a: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
adduser is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjetty8-extra-java : Depends: libtomcat7-java (>= 7.0.28) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: install Java with `sudo apt-get install 
openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-6-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-headless libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java openjdk-7-source openjdk-7-jre-lib openjdk-7-demo openjdk-6-source openjdk-6-jre-lib openjdk-6-demo openjdk-7-doc openjdk-6-doc jarwrapper` and jetty as in the first answer.

Comment: I got the same "broken packages" error when I tried to install jetty. I added to my question.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get remove libtomcat7-java` and run the process again.

Comment: I see that I have now `java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)` instead of 7 and this is causing a problem with jetty which is compiled with v7. How can i fix this?

Comment: Is there a error message ? It is not 1.6.0_7 even though it say. Can you post that full error message even.

Comment: I upgreaded java and that solved that problem but now I am getting "Address already in use" error. I posted a question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/394092/address-already-in-use-error-when-trying-to-run-jetty-with-ubuntu-server Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try with installing the [followings](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/jetty):

```
sudo apt-get install jetty libjetty8-extra-java libjetty8-java libjetty-extra-java libjetty-extra libjetty-java-doc jetty8 libjetty8-java-doc libjetty-java jsvc default-jre-headless apache2-utils adduser
```

Comment: I tried it but I got broken packages error. What should I do?

Comment: That means you have installed `libtomcat7-java` from other repository. Or you may have Upgraded from 12.10 ? First see uninstalling `libtomcat7-java`. Then install above packages. If not succeed, you may need to remove that older repository or need to do pinning.

Comment: Or instead of `default-jre-headless` add `java5-runtime-headless` to above list.

Comment: Ok, I ran java5-runtime-headless but it asks me to choose one explicitly. Which one do I choose? I edited my question with EDIT 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry. main package should be added first. Add `openjdk-7-jre-headless` to the above list.

Comment: This did not work either. I added EDIT 3.

Comment: No , I meant remove  and add `openjdk-7-jre-headless`. So now remove `java5-runtime-headless` from the list. It is provided by the package, `openjdk-7-jre-headless`. There is no package named `java5-runtime-headless`.

Comment: I removed java5-runtime-headless but I get the error The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjetty8-extra-java : Depends: libtomcat7-java (>= 7.0.28) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: this is what I ran: `sudo apt-get install jetty openjdk-7-jre-headless libjetty8-extra-java libjetty8-java libjetty-extra-java libjetty-extra libjetty-java-doc jetty8 libjetty8-java-doc libjetty-java jsvc  apache2-utils adduser`

Comment: Ok. it seems better if `libtomcat7-java` is removed. sometimes you may need to remove the repository. or may need to do pinning. Follow 4 th in [this](http://allfreeubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-troubleshoot-with-command-line.html)post

Comment: I did another clean install ubuntu 13.10. Can you help to install Java and jetty from scratch?